# Authorize or not the access to the package using android PackageManager

Tags: android, security

I juste made the following test:

- APK1 : com.sample.apk1 : signed with certificate1
- APK2 : com.sampla.apk2 : signed with certificate2 different from certificate2

APK1 can access the content of the package APK2 (I made the test for a layout that I inflated) using :

```
PackageInfo pkInfo = pkManager.getPackageInfo("com.sampla.apk2", 0);
Resources res = pkManager.getResourcesForApplication(pkInfo.packageName);
```

How could it be possible ?
How can I prevent APK1 from accessing the APK2 ?

Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

> How could it be possible ?

Resources and assets are world-readable.

> How can I prevent APK1 from accessing the APK2 ?

Do not install APK2.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. Can I verify whether APK1 and APK2 are signed with the with the same certificate or not?

Comment: @Anaseh: I seem to recall that you can get at certificate information through `PackageManager`, though I have not tried comparing the values. Moreover, that does not change the fact that APK2's resources will be readable by APK1, APK3, APK4, through APKN.